# Why module not found error in react native?

Tags: react-native

```
error Could not find the following native modules: RNFBAnalytics, RNFBApp, RNFBCrashlytics, react-native-config, react-native-date-picker, RNDeviceInfo, ReactNativeExceptionHandler, RNGestureHandler, BVLinearGradient, RNReanimated, RNScreens, react-native-splash-screen, react-native-sqlite-storage, RNUserAgent. Did you forget to run "pod install" ?
```

this is happening after upgrading react native version to
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.63.2",

After running react-native run-ios i am getting following error. I have already did pod install but still getting same error.

is there any way or root cause for this?

Comment: You might need to manually add the dependencies to your pod file. But it depends on your react native version and the library. I'd recommend you to go through the configuration of the libraries you're using and seeing if you've configured everything correctly.

Comment: @BasvanderLinden thanks for input.. i have updated my question with react native version.. can you please suggest in more details..as i am new in react-native... what you you mean by configuration?

Comment: Because you're using a react native version after 0.60 auto linking should take care of most of the work when installing libraries, but there could be times where it doesn't and you need to take extra steps to get it to work. With configuration I mean the installation instructions for the libraries you're using. It is kind of tedious work, but google the native modules the error's saying can't be found and probably the first search result in most cases will list the installation instructions. First try the automatic installation with your package manager...

Comment: And try the manual installation if it doesn't work. For example the automatic installation for Realtime Database can be found here https://rnfirebase.io/database/usage. And the manual linking approach for iOS can be found here https://rnfirebase.io/crashlytics/usage/installation/ios. Repeat the process until everything works. So there's not really a straightforward answer, because instructions can depend on the library, and you're using a lot of libraries.